# SUMIF() dynamic range function

Tags: dynamic, google-sheets, range

I wrote a SUMIF() statement that works, when I manually select the range on which I want to sum, but I want to have a function, which I can put below the range that I want to sum and it should automatically extent the range to a certain breakpoint above the range.

So for example I have a list where I want to sum the column 'duration' and double the sum if there is '2' in column '$' and sum the rest without doubling it when there is a '1' in column '$':

```
C    D
$    duration
1    1:40
2    2:30
1    3:30
1    1:50

$    duration
2    5:50
1    2:30
2    4:20
```

I already figured out how to do that but I have multiple ranges which I want to sum with the SUMIF() statement I wrote. The breakpoint in this case would be the $.

Is there a possibility to do this in a Google Sheets?

Comment: In your example, where is the sum must be placed? Is it column D, or E? In my opinion, the best way is to create additional column with name or number of group (1, 2, 3..) and then use `sumproduct` finction.

Comment: Hello Max, Thank you for your answer, The sum should be below column C. I already have the SUMIF function and it works, but I want to auto-select the range, when I put the function below column C. Now I have to edit the function for every time I want to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
OFFSET($C$1,MATCH("$",OFFSET($C$1,,,row()-1)),,row()-1-MATCH("$",OFFSET($C$1,,,row()-1))),
OFFSET($D$1,MATCH("$",OFFSET($C$1,,,row()-1)),,row()-1-MATCH("$",OFFSET($C$1,,,row()-1))))
```

---

This is complicated. But this part `MATCH("$",OFFSET($C$1,,,row()-1))` is used 4 times in the formula. You may use column E to count it:

```
=MATCH("$",OFFSET($C$1,,,row()-1))
```

And then final formula will look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET($C$1,E6,,row()-1-E6),OFFSET($D$1,E6,,row()-1-E6))
```

Comment: Sorry, could only try it now. Thank you so much!!! This works! I am so happy right now!